# Key for two strings in a map?

Tags: java, dictionary, tuples, apache-commons

I need to create a map that has a key of two strings.

for example lets say

```
key = Name & Target
value = Permission(boolean)
```

Do I need to create a special object or is there any build in tuple in Java/Google Collections or Commons Collections or Commons Lang?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apache Commons Collections has [MultiKey](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/keyvalue/MultiKey.html):

```
map.put(new MultiKey(key1, key2), value);
```

and a [MultiKeyMap](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/MultiKeyMap.html):

```
multiKeyMap.put(key1, key2, value);
```

Answer (score 4):

why dont you create a `List` from those two Strings and use as a Key in `Map`. It would keep the code more readable also.

Comment: Please post a working example for suggested solution ,it can be handy for further reference

Answer (score 3):

You could cat the strings together but my personal preference is to create a little value object:

```
public class NameTarget {
    private final String name;
    private final String target;

    public NameTarget(String name, String target){
        this.name = name;
        this.target = target;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((target == null) ? 0 : target.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        NameTarget other = (NameTarget) obj;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        if (target == null) {
            if (other.target != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!target.equals(other.target))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    // add getters here
}
```

That took about 30 seconds to generate do in eclipse, it makes for a more type safe and cleaner code to work with in the long run.

You could and I have in the past created a `Pair` style turple but I'm starting to prefer the named immutable value types for this sort of thing.

Comment: Can confirm the 30 seconds - you manually write a package name, a class name and the two attributes, the rest is autogenerated be eclipse (constructor, getter, setter, implementations for hashcode, toString and equals)

Comment: It's not about speed, but about readability.  MultiKey, Pair, or just a List says nothing about what the key actually represents.  And if you need to use these two strings as a key, they probably have a functional meaning.  In some rare cases, it's even useful to wrap a single value in a value type just for the sake of representing meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
String name = ...
String target = ...
String key = name + "_" + target;

map.put(key, value)
```

Alternatively you can create an object which hold two strings and override the `hashCode` and `equals` routines to differentiate in a better way than simple string concatenation.

Comment: This may not be the best solution, name='ab' and target='c' will point at the same entry as name='a' and target='bc'. Not perfect solution but those strings can be separated by some unusual string.